# Implementing of Russian locale into Unity text to speech recognition plugin for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Guys 
I've implemented into my Unity project a plugin which can be downloaded at the link (https://github.com/HoseinPorazar/Android-Native-TTS-plugin-for-Unity-3d).

To use it you need: 
1-import AndroidNativeTTS.unitypackage into your project 
2-create an empty game object and rename it to tts. 
3-attach test script and TextToSpeech script to tts game object. 
4-add a button and set the on click event to test.Speak(). 
5-build project for Android platform.

After implementing the plugin to make it work it's necessary to delete in AndroidManifext.xml the line "android:label=NAtive TTS".

AndroidManifest.xml is stored in the directory "Assets\Plugin\Android\androidtts-release.aar"

When I implemented the plugin which is build to use "UK" and "US" locale, I tried to add Russian locale but unfortunately it failed.

Please see the scripts below (Test.cs and TextToSpeach.cs):

test.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour {

TextToSpeech tts;
void Start()
{

    tts = GetComponent<TextToSpeech>();
}
public void Speak()
{
    tts.Speak("hello mr hosein porazar kasin", (string msg) =>
    {
        tts.ShowToast(msg);
    });
}
public void ChangeSpeed()
{
    tts.SetSpeed(0.5f);
}
public void ChangeLanguage()
{
    tts.SetLanguage(TextToSpeech.Locale.UK);
}
public void ChangePitch()
{
    tts.SetPitch(0.6f);
}
}
```

TextToSpeech.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class TextToSpeech :MonoBehaviour
{
void Start()
{


}
public enum Locale
{
    UK = 0,
    US = 1

}
private AndroidJavaObject TTSExample = null;
private AndroidJavaObject activityContext = null;
private Locale _lang;
public Locale Language { get { return _lang; } set { SetLanguage(value); } }
private float _pitch, _speed;
public float Pitch { get{return _pitch;} set { SetPitch(value); } }
public float Speed { get{return _speed;} set { SetSpeed(value); } }

public delegate void OnErrorCallbackHandler(string error);
private OnErrorCallbackHandler _callback;
public TextToSpeech()
{
    //Initialize();
}
public TextToSpeech(Locale language)
{
    Initialize();
    this.Language = language;
    SetLanguage(this.Language);
}
public TextToSpeech(Locale language,float speed,float pitch)
{
    Initialize();
    this.Language = language;
    this.Pitch = pitch;
    this.Speed = speed;
    SetLanguage(this.Language);
    SetSpeed(this.Speed);
    SetPitch(this.Pitch);
}
public void Speak(string toSay,OnErrorCallbackHandler callback)
{
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    this._callback = callback;


    TTSExample.Call("TTSMEWithCallBack", toSay, gameObject.name, "OnError");

}
    public void OnError(string error)
{
    if (_callback != null)
    {
        if (error.Length > 0)
        {
            _callback.Invoke(error);
        }
    }
    ShowToast(error);
}
public void Speak(string toSay)
{
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    TTSExample.Call("TTSME", toSay);

}
public void SetLanguage(Locale lan)
{
    this._lang = lan;
    string[] Language = new string[] {"UK","US" };
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    TTSExample.Call("SetLang", Language[(int)lan]);
}
public void SetSpeed(float speed)
{
    this._speed = speed;
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    TTSExample.Set<float>("Speed", speed);
}
public void SetPitch(float pitch)
{
    this._pitch = pitch;
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    TTSExample.Set<float>("Pitch", pitch);
}
private void Initialize()
{
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("ir.hoseinporazar.androidtts.TTS"))
        {
            if (pluginClass != null)
            {
                TTSExample = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                TTSExample.Call("setContext", activityContext);              

            }
        }
    }


}
public void ShowToast(string msg)
{

    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        using (AndroidJavaClass activityClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
        {
            activityContext = activityClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        }

        using (AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("ir.hoseinporazar.androidtts.TTS"))
        {
            if (pluginClass != null)
            {
                TTSExample = pluginClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("instance");
                TTSExample.Call("setContext", activityContext);
                activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
                {
                    TTSExample.Call("showMessage", msg);
                }));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        activityContext.Call("runOnUiThread", new AndroidJavaRunnable(() =>
        {
            TTSExample.Call("showMessage", msg);
        }));
    }
}
```

}

I've tried to format following lines to change the language to Russian but it didn't help me:

```
public enum Locale
{
    RU = 0,
    US = 1

}

public void SetLanguage(Locale lan)
{
    this._lang = lan;
    string[] Language = new string[] {"RU","US" };
    if (TTSExample == null)
    {
        Initialize();
    }
    TTSExample.Call("SetLang", Language[(int)lan]);
}
```

I also tried to contatct the developer of the plugin but it seems he was last time on github a couple years ago.
I'd really appreciate it if somebody can help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On the plugin homepage, the author says...

> I have included 2 languages (UK,and US) if you want to use other
>   languages you will have to modify plugin ( with Android Studio).

So it seems you will also need to change switch statement at the bottom of the Java code here:

https://github.com/HoseinPorazar/Android-Native-TTS-plugin-for-Unity-3d/blob/master/NativeAndroidTTS/androidtts/src/main/java/ir/hoseinporazar/androidtts/TTS.java

By adding an `"RU"` case like this...

```
public void SetLang(String loc){
    switch (loc){
        case "UK":
            if(t1!=null)
            t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            break;
        case "US":
            if(t1!=null)
            t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            break;
        case "RU":
            if(t1!=null)
            t1.setLanguage(Locale.RU);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I made changes and tried to rebuild the plugin but had too many mistakes in android studio without knowing how to resolve them. I suppose the plugin is a bit old. So I'm going to look for another plugin, cause I'm not yet experienced in java and Android Studio.